# Dirac propagator in Peskin & Schroeder's Book

Tags: notation, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

I read Quantum Field Theory Book written by Peskin & Schroeder, and when a commutator about Dirac field is compile,
he compile a general commutator:
$$ [\psi_a(x),\overline{\psi}_b(x)] $$ having terms that combine $$ u^s_a(p) \overline{u}^s_b = (\not p +m)_{ab} $$ I know $$ u^s(p) \overline{u}^s = \not p +m $$ what exactly does this $$ (..)_{ab}$$ means? Sometimes, it will be dropped, when can I drop them?

Answer (score 3):

These are just the spinor indices. You can drop them as long as you make sure the order of the spinors is correct.